# Cramér's Model - “The Prime Numbers and Their Distribution” - Part 2

Tags: probability, number-theory, prime-numbers

Following a previous [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/680122/cram%C3%A9rs-model-the-prime-numbers-and-their-distribution-part-1) (here you'll find an introduction):

The book states that using the convergence of the binomial distribution towards the Poisson distribution, it's easy to show that $$|\{x\le\xi:\pi_S(x+\lambda \log x)-\pi_S(x)=k\}|\sim\xi\mathrm e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^k}{k!}\quad(\xi\to\infty)$$ holds almost surely.

I couldn't prove this.