# Cramér's Model - “The Prime Numbers and Their Distribution” - Part 3

Tags: probability, number-theory, prime-numbers

Following a previous [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/884902/cram%C3%A9rs-model-the-prime-numbers-and-their-distribution-part-2) ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/680122/cram%C3%A9rs-model-the-prime-numbers-and-their-distribution-part-1) you'll find an introduction):

The book states that almost surely $$\pi_S(x+y)-\pi_S(x)=\mathrm{li}(x+y)-\mathrm{li}(x)+O(\sqrt y)$$ as soon as $y/(\log x)^2\to\infty$, with $y\le x$.

I couldn't prove this.

Comment: Assuming the Riemann hypothesis